# 2 сайта на одном IP и порту и 2 SSL IIS как подружить?

Tags: ssl, iis

Есть 2 сайта: site1.ru и site2.ru. Они оба управляются IIS на Windows Server 2019. Есть 2 сертификата SSL, сделанных по [этой статье](https://winitpro.ru/index.php/2017/11/03/ustanovka-besplatnogo-ssl-sertifikata-lets-encrypt-na-iis-v-windows-server-2012-r2/). Проблем с запуском сайтов нет. Проблема только с сертификатами - если оба на порту 443, то один из них корректно не работает. Если, например, на сайт site1.ru назначить 443 порт, а на site2.ru -- 444, то всё работает идеально. Подскажите, как решить проблему.

Comment: Наверное надо погуглить в сторону iis sni

Comment: На этапе add binding поставьте опцию Require Server Name Indication

Comment: Спасибо, iis sni помогло